# Should I use node.js + express or Rails + Juggernaut to build a chat room?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, juggernaut

I'm trying to build a chatroom in the conventional sense to operate in the browser but with a decent API layer allowing for decent abstraction between the server and the client.

I want to keep it SIMPLE, but still have room to develop extra functionality going forwards, such as saving transcripts in the database.

Comment: did you add a look at the examples of the server side of socket.io http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use faye.

https://github.com/jcoglan/faye

There is also a Railscast for this
http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

Answer (score 0):

You could consider leveraging [Faye](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) which is built on top of Node.js and I believe has WebSockets support too.  Possibly route all transcripts with Redis storage.